Questions exist tagged 'ida' and 'idapro'
The tag ida is a synonym for idapro, so there should only be questions tagged idapro. However, as the tag page reveals, there are three questions tagged ida. 1 3
How does this happen, despite these tags being synonyms?

Actually, the official name of the program (since a few years ago) is just "IDA". "IDA Professional" is what was previously called "IDA Pro Advanced".

Poof! They are gone. 

On a serious note, that is normal behavior. Those questions were tagged with ida before the synonym relation to idapro was made. Tag synonyms affect future associations, whereas past tagging needs to be handled explicitly/manually.  I just did the retags.
